# LINQ to SQL: Reuse lambda expression

Tags: linq-to-sql

I stumbled over some strange LINQ to SQL behaviour - can anybody shed some light on this?

I want to define a lambda expression and use it in my LINQ statement. The following code works fine:

```
[...]
Func<Table1, bool> lambda = x => x.Id > 1000;
var result = dataContext.Table1s.Where(lambda);
[...]
```

But when I try to use my lambda expression in a statement on an associated table

```
[...]
Func<Table1, bool> lambda = x => x.Id > 1000;
var result = dataContext.Table2s.Where(x => x.Table1s.Any(lambda));
[...]
```

I get an exception:

```
Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Any'.
```

But, and this I don't get: It works fine when I put my lambda directly into the query:

```
[...]
var result = dataContext.Table2s.Where(x => x.Table1s.Any(y => y.Id > 1000));
[...]
```

WHY?!

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `var lamda = x => x.Id > 1000;`. Don't know it'll help, but it might...

Comment: @Alxandr - that's not legal actually. Lambda expressions can be compiled to either `Func<>` or `Expression<Func<>>` and in your example the compiler won't be able to tell which one you want, and will throw an error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Okay, here's the deal: `dataContext.Table1s` is of type `IQueryable<T>`. `IQueryable<T>` defines `Where` and `Any` methods that take a predicate of type `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. The `Expression<>` wrapper is critical, as this is what allows LINQ to SQL to translate your lambda expression to SQL and execute it on the database server.

However, `IQueryable<T>` also includes `IEnumerable<T>`. `IEnumerable<T>` also defines `Where` and `Any` methods, but the IEnumerable version takes a predicate of type `Func<T, bool>`. Because this is a compiled function and not an expression, it can't be translated to SQL. As a result, this code...

```
Func<Table1, bool> lambda = x => x.Id > 1000;
var result = dataContext.Table1s.Where(lambda);
```

...will pull EVERY record out of `Table1s` into memory, and then filter the records in memory. It works, but it's really bad news if your table is large.

```
Func<Table1, bool> lambda = x => x.Id > 1000;
var result = dataContext.Table2s.Where(x => x.Table1s.Any(lambda));
```

This version has two lambda expressions. The second one, being passed directly into `Where`, is an `Expression` that includes a reference to a `Func`. You can't mix the two, and the error message you're getting is telling you that the call to `Any` is expecting an `Expression` but you're passing in a `Func`.

```
var result = dataContext.Table2s.Where(x => x.Table1s.Any(y => y.Id > 1000));
```

In this version, your inner lambda is automatically being converted to an `Expression` because that's the only choice if you want your code to be transformed into SQL by LINQ to SQL. In the other cases, you're forcing the lambda to be a `Func` instead of an `Expression` - in this case you're not, so it works.

What's the solution? It's actually pretty simple:

```
Expression<Func<Table1, bool>> lambda = x => x.Id > 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it won't compile, the compiler error is:
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Table1,bool>>' to 'System.Func<Table1,bool>'

Comment: That error message seems to indicate that you're calling `Where` or an `Any` on an object that implements IEnumerable but not IQueryable - because the [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) versions expect a Func, where the [IQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548547.aspx) versions expect an Expression. If it won't accept an Expression, the object may not be IQueryable...

Comment: It's defined as an EntitySet, as generated by SQLMetal/the Visual Studio Designer for LINQ to SQL table associations.

Comment: [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2011/01/05/linq-macros.aspx) might be of help in your situation...

Comment: Thanks for the link, Joel. It doesn't solve my above problem, but it's very useful anyway and gave me some new ideas :)

Comment: @JoelMueller article is not available now :(

Answer (score 0):

Does `Table1` refer to the same namespace? In the first example you're querying against the `Table1` objects that are directly under `dataContext`, in the second example you're querying against the `Table1` objects that is a property of the `Table2` objects, and in the last example you're using a anonymous function which fix the issue.

I would look up the type of the `Table1` objects that is a property of a `Table2` object and compare it to a `Table1` object that is connected directly to the `dataContext`. My guess is that they differ and your lambda expression is using the type of the object that is connected to the `dataContext`.