# Reuse of a LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, reusability

This is not about the reuse of a result but more the statement itself. 
Nor is it about an error when using var as mentioned in: [LINQ to SQL: Reuse lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562132)

Out of sheer curiosity I was wondering if it is possible to reuse a single LINQ statement.

Lets say I have the following LINQ statement:

```
.Where(x => x.Contains(""));
```

Is it possible to extract the statement `x => x.Contains("")` and use some kind of reference to this for later usage in, lets say, another class?

So I can call it like: `.Where(previouslySavedStatement);`

Comment: put it in a variable. `Func<string, bool> func = x => x.contains("");`

Comment: @wudzik This isn't a duplicate. The duplicate reference refers to re-using results, the question asks about re-using the query itself.

Comment: Thanks Shlomo :) just made the edit myself

Comment: @Shlomo sorry, missunderstood question, reopened

Comment: `Func<string, bool> previouslySavedStatement = x => x.Contains("")` or `Expression<Func<string, bool>>` if the source is an `IQueryable`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL: Reuse lambda expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562132/linq-to-sql-reuse-lambda-expression)

Comment: @RobertMcKee I have looked at the link you posted but the problem there is between var / func<> it can be used to answer my question but in the base it is different. So no 'similairity'

Comment: @Blaatz0r The answer for that and this is the same.  The first answer in the link I gave says that for LINQ over SQL (and LINQ over EF) is `Expression<Func<Table1, bool>> lambda = x => x.Id > 1000;`  and `Func<Table1, bool> lambda = x => x.Id > 1000;` for IEnumerables which is the same as the answer you marked correct.  The "base" is the same.  IEnumerables take lamdas/delegates, while IQueryables take expressions to build expression trees.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can store it in a variable. If you are working with `IQueryable` then use:

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> selector = x => x.Contains("");
```

If you are using `IEnumerable` then use:

```
Func<Foo, bool> selector = x => x.Contains("");
```

And use it in your query:

```
query.Where(selector);
```

Comment: FYI to @Blaatz0r If you are working with a `IEnumerable<T>` instead of a `IQueryable<T>` you would only use `Func<Foo, bool> selector = ...`, but if you are using `IQueryable<T>` you most defiantly want to use the `Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>` version.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Most of my statements are IEnumerable<T> so thanks for the heads up

Comment: @Blaatz0r if you have the expression version you can also convert it in to a delegate by doing `Func<Foo, bool> selector2 = selector.Compile();`, you can't go the other direction from a delegate to a expression.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can write a function containing the query you want to reuse, which takes and returns an IQueryable<T>

```
   public IQueryable<T> ContainsEmpty(IQueryable<T> query)
   {
       return query.Where(x => x.Contains(""));
   }
```

Now you can reuse it:

```
   query1 = ContainsEmpty(query1);
   query2 = ContainsEmpty(another);
```

Comment: +1 This does not directly answer OP's question, but it's a much better way of solving his problem _(though, why did you choose `IQueryable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`?)_

Comment: The datatype isn't specified in the question, but it does mention "LINQ to SQL" and has "query" in the title, so I guessed IQueryable :-)

Answer (score 5):

It depends. There's two `Where` methods, `Enumerable.Where` and `Queryable.Where`. If you're applying the `.Where` to an `IEnumerable` than the first one is called, if you're applying it to an `IQueryable` the second one is called.

Since `Enumerable.Where` takes in a `Func`, it isn't reusable. Since `Queryable.Where` takes in an expression, it is reusable. You can do so as follows:

```
var x = new List<string>().AsQueryable();

var query = x.Where (n => n.Contains("some string"));

//Extract the lambda clause
var expr = query.Expression;
var methodExpr = (MethodCallExpression)expr;
var quoteExpr = (UnaryExpression)methodExpr.Arguments[1];
var funcExpr = (Expression<Func<string, bool>>)quoteExpr.Operand;
```

You can then later re-apply the where expression:

```
var query2 = x.Where(funcExpr);
```

Comment: Yes, I even read the accepted answer, and I even read the question too. I even believe my answer answers the question as even asked better than the accepted answer even did.

Comment: `var methodExpr = (MethodCallExpression)expr;` seems less clean than just `MethodCallExpression methodExpr = expr;`

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a library to address exactly this concern, it's called CLinq and you can find an implementation for the EntityFramework here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CLinq.EntityFramework

It allows to create query snippets and use them everywhere you in a linq query. Following the example of Hamid, create the following expression:

`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> selector = x => x.Contains("");`

You can now use this query everywhere in your linq queries like this:

`query.AsComposable().Where(o => selector.Pass(o));`

Additionally to this simple example you're also able to combine your query snippets:

`query.AsComposable().Where(o => selector.Pass(o) || anotherSelector.Pass(o));`

or even merge them together:

`query.AsComposable().Where(o => anotherSelector.Pass(selector.Pass(o)));`

There's some more features, but I think it's really helpful, so check it out :)