# Is it possible to put parts of a Linq statement in a variable?

Tags: c#, linq, variables

I am coming from Perl doing first steps with C# and Linq.
My question is if there is a way to put **parts of a Linq statement in a variable** like this (Code only for short illustration, not tested) to use it several times more easily and flexible than writing it new every time. Also one could use different Order-Statements (Select-Case, Array) for the same MQuery.

```
var orderstatement = "orderby m.Reihenfolge ascending, m.Datum descending, m.Titel ascending";

var MQuery = (from m in _context.Movie
               orderstatement
               where m.Sichtbar == true && m.Gesperrt == false
               select m;
```

Thanks for advising.

Comment: Yes-ish. You should learn about [Linq Method Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq#lambda-expressions).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reuse of a LINQ query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337294/reuse-of-a-linq-query)

Comment: OrderBy yes, but better to post more details and samples. LINQ is complex thing from the first sign.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this with extension methods. First, define the order by movies method

```
public static IQueryable<Movie> OrderMovies(this IQueryable<Movie> movies) {
         return movies.OrderBy(m => m.Reihenfolge).ThenByDescending(m => m.Datum).ThenBy(m => m.Title);
}
```

And then use it in the movies query

```
var movies = _context.Movies.Where(m => m.Sichtbar == true && m.Gesperrt == false).OrderMovies().Select(m => m)
```